# Do function onclick button

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve this. I have a input field and a submit button. First thing i wanna do is change the value of a variable to the value of the input field when the submit button is clicked.

Secondly I want to run a function when the submit button is clicked. he case: When the submit button is clicked i want to retrieve a json file from wikipedia based on the value of the input field.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8"><p>Please enter your searchterm:</p>
        <input id="input" type="text"  value="Denmark"><br>
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4"><div id="result"></div></div>
    </div>
 </div>


<script>
var searchTerm="";
var url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + searchTerm+"&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";

$('#submit').click(function (){
searchTerm='denmark';
});


$.getJSON(url,function fetchWiki(data){
  wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
  $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");
  $("#result").append($wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html());
});
```

I can't figure out how to change the value and run the function after that.

Please bear with me, i am relatively new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the click event:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e){ //pass the event into the function
 e.preventDefault(); //prevent the submit button from actually submitting

 //update your variables
 searchTerm = $("#input").val();
 url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=" + searchTerm+"&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";


 $.getJSON(url,function fetchWiki(data){
   wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
   $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");
   $("#result").append($wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html());
  });

});
```

Also, notice that the code that does the search needs to go **inside** the click function, because the variables need to be updated **after** they click "submit".

Comment: You also need to change the url *after* getting the searchTerm from the input. Otherwise it's pretty useless.

Comment: Actually i already tried this approach without luck. When i click on the button nothing happens, and i can't figure out why.

Comment: Sorry i was a bit fast there. After clicking the button the json is loaded. But if i change the value in the input field and click again nothing happens.

Comment: It's working, but I think you meant to do `$("#result").html`, not `$("#result").append`. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xGtE/ Also, if you put an invalid search term, nothing happens. I put in "USA" and it works fine.

Comment: It is working. I just wasn't thinking straight. Thank you very much - this took me days to figure out.